# Ennio Morricone's Ancora Qui first seconds

Tags: classical-music, history, piano

I feel the first piano musical notes, the very first secondes of Ancora Qui come from another classical music that'd be as famous as Ancora Qui. Unfortunately, I don't know which song and I have no proof, but it sounds like a deja vu, or a already listened actually.

Am I totally wrong and does Morricone is the original creator of these notes?

[Ancora Qui — YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Br2BBJt-JU8)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first few notes originate from "Für Elise" by Beethoven, [see Wikipedia for a recording](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/F%C3%BCr_Elise)